# passport.authenticate() using a Promise instead of a Custom Callback

Tags: node.js, authentication, promise, passport.js

`passport.authenticate()`, how can I define a **Promise** instead of using a **Custom Ballback**?

How to used `passport.authenticate()` is referenced within here:
http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/

Within this page, there is a section **Custom Ballback**:

> If the built-in options are not sufficient for handling an authentication request, a custom callback can be provided to allow the application to handle success or failure.

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

The **Custom Callback** is defined as:

```
function(err, user, info){...}
```

What I wish to do is replace this **Custom Callback** with a **Promise**.

```
[Promise](resolve, reject)
.then(res => {
})
.catch(err => {
})
```

How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Can't your custom callback just return a promise?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I could give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your helpful responses @sterling-archer and @el-finito

I had found a related issue within Passport.js Github repository helpful for using Passport to handle passport.authenticate() callback:
["Using node's promisify with passport"](http://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/605)

```
export const authenticate = (req, res) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    passport.authenticate(
      [passport strategy],
      { session: false },
      (err, user) => {
        if (err) reject(new Error(err))
        else if (!user) reject(new Error('Not authenticated'))
        resolve(user)
      })(req, res)
    })
```

Comment: I'm getting:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.authenticate

When trying to do like this, any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [es6-promisify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promisify) package. It is very easy to use, here is an example:

```
const {promisify} = require("es6-promisify");

// Convert the stat function
const fs = require("fs");
const stat = promisify(fs.stat);

// Now usable as a promise!
stat("example.txt").then(function (stats) {
    console.log("Got stats", stats);
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.error("Yikes!", err);
});
```

Comment: I trying out the following: "Using node's promisify with passport": https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/605