# how to convert this Callback Authentication to Promise in nodejs mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am using Nodejs Mongoose here But when i Try to replace Callback to promise It Gives me an error
(Failed to serialize user into session)
Please Help Me........

```js
var localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const user = require('./mongoBase/userSc.js');

const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

module.exports = function(passport) {
        passport.use(new localStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, (email, password, done) => {
            email = email.toLowerCase();
            user.findOne({ email: email }, (err, data) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (!data) {
                    return done(null, false, { message: "User Doesn't Exists.." });
                }
                bcrypt.compare(password, data.password, (err, match) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return done(null, false);
                    }
                    if (!match) {
                        return done(null, false, { message: "Password Doesn't Match" });
                    }
                    if (match) {
                        return done(null, data);
                    }
                });
            });
        }));

        passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
            cb(null, user.id);
        });

        passport.deserializeUser(function(id, cb) {
            user.findById(id, function(err, user) {
                cb(err, user);
            });
        });
    }
    // ---------------
    // end of autentication statregy
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about which callback you want to convert to Promise? Also 
 have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328833/passport-authenticate-using-a-promise-instead-of-a-custom-callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code for passport with spotify, maybe it could help you some. If your question is answered by this answer, please click the checkbox beside the answer.

```
module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.use(
        new SpotifyStrategy(
          {
            clientID: 'CLIENT ID',
            clientSecret: 'CLIENT SECRET',
            callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8888/auth/spotify/callback',
          },
          async (accessToken, refreshToken, expires_in, profile, done) => {
            // Do async operations
            
                    
              async function checking() {
                // Do async operations
              }  

              await checking();

              return done(null, profile);
   
          }         
        )
      );

      // Serialize
      passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user);
      });
      
      passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
          done(null, user);
      });
```